# ZHS Permission Problem on Proton generation on MacM1

Tags: flutter, dart, backend, protocol-buffers, code-generation

I am using Apple MacBook Air with M2 Chip to develop softwares and etc. Currently my company using protocol buffers to serialize entity models. I am having issues with generating Dart files through using protoc.

I used
`$ brew install protobuf` and run `$ protoc --version` to check installation. Terminal prompts **libprotoc 23.4**.

However, when I use following code block to generate files,

```
mkdir lib/src/shared/dart_gen

protoc --dart_out=grpc:lib/src/shared/dart_gen --proto_path=lib/src/shared/proto `
    lib/src/shared/proto/shared.proto `
    lib/src/shared/proto/consumer/consumer.proto `
    lib/src/shared/proto/order/order.proto `
```

Terminal promts

```
mkdir: lib/src/shared/dart_gen: File exists
zsh: permission denied: lib/src/shared/proto/shared.proto
Missing input file.
zsh: permission denied: lib/src/shared/proto/order/order.proto
zsh: permission denied: lib/src/shared/proto/consumer/consumer.proto
```

Note:

- I tried Give Terminal Full Access to the Disk from Privacy and Security Settings and it didn't work.

I tried to generate some Proto-dart files through using protoc on terminal.(Apple M2 Chip)

Comment: **Solved**

I do not know why, but it was never about the **permissions**.

I used followings to solved the issue
`mkdir lib/src/shared/dart_gen
protoc --dart_out=grpc:lib/src/shared/dart_gen --proto_path=lib/src/shared/proto lib/src/shared/proto/*/*.proto` for lib/src/shared/proto has multiple folders that contains balbla.proto files

Comment: Please don't add things like (SOLVED) to question titles, nor post the solution in the question or the comments. Instead, post and **answer** with the solution, and accept it after the timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why, but it was never about the permissions. I used followings to solved the issue `mkdir lib/src/shared/dart_gen protoc --dart_out=grpc:lib/src/shared/dart_gen --proto_path=lib/src/shared/proto lib/src/shared/proto/*/*.proto` for lib/src/shared/proto has multiple folders that contains balbla.proto files –